# sometimes on saving a post as draft, it says Access Denied You don't have permission to access “mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php”

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

It only occurs sometimes, when i try to save a post as a draft, with a content having anchor target="_blank", it throws an error on saving `Access Denied`

[image]

I set up it locally and its working fine.

I tried below code, but didnt worked.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```